# How to only display arbitrary values on a y-axis in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm looking for a way to set specific values on a y-axis. I have five datasets on a scatter chart and I would like to only show max values of three of them on a separate y axis.
[Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tK7Q.png)

My current approach ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCmiY.png)):

```
{
        type: 'linear',
        id: 'secondary',
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontColor: '#466696',
          fontSize: 14,
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          callback: function (val) {
            return '$' + val;
          }
        },
        afterBuildTicks: function (scale) {
          scale.ticks = [ctrl.statePension, ctrl.statePension + ctrl.pensionSavings, ctrl.statePension + ctrl.pensionSavings + ctrl.insuranceValue];
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        }
      }
```

It kind of works, but labels close to each other overlap despite autoSkip being enabled. Is there a way to replicate the behavior from the first image?